# ReactJs: Uncaught Error: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting this error on my Reactjs App. **The point to note that I'm using the class instead of ID.**

```
Uncaught Error: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.
```

This is my Js code

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
require('./style.css')

var App = require('./components/App')

ReactDOM.render( <App/>, document.getElementsByClassName('app') );
```

And my Html Code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>React App</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="app"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do querySelectorAll, getElementsByClassName and other getElementsBy\* methods return?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method)

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('app')` returns a collection of all the elements, you need to use it like this: `document.getElementsByClassName('app')[0]` or use `id` instead of `class`, like this: `document.getElementById('app')` and define `id='app'` in html file.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `document.getElementsByClassName('app')` returns array of elements and you need element itself.

Just use such code: `document.getElementsByClassName('app')[0]`